# FTP Detect if active or passive modes are enabled

Tags: python, ftp, twisted

Specifically for Twisted, I would like to be able to determine whether the server I am connected to supports active or passive mode. See [API](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.protocols.ftp.FTPClient.html).

If somebody could explain or give example in FTP protocol how you can determine whether the server supports active or passive modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passive mode is enabled by issuing the `PASV` command to the server.  If it responds with an error code (should be `500 Unknown command`) upon issuing that command, then you know that it is not supported. If it responds with a `227 Entering Passive Mode`, then you know that passive is supported.

Example using command line telnet and FTP commands:

```
% telnet ftp.mozilla.org 21
Trying 63.245.208.138...
Connected to dm-ftp01.mozilla.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220-  [greeting omitted]
USER anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
PASS jathanism@
230-  [banner omitted]
230 Login successful.
```

Good command (passive mode is supported):

```
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (63,245,208,138,202,53)
```

Bad command (500 error thrown):

```
FART
500 Unknown command.
```

Comment: In a successful `PASV` reply, only the response code is standardized (always 227), but the text containing the IP/Port is not standardized. It differs from one FTP server vendor to another. Not all vendors say "Entering Passive Mode", not all vendors wrap the IP/Port in parenthesis, some vendors put the IP/Port at the start of the text whereas other vendors put it at the end of the text, etc. You have to scan the text looking for the IP/Port, you can't make any assumptions about its formatting. This is discussed in [RFC 1123 Section 4.1.2.6](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123#page-31).