# Check if FTP server is passive or active using Telnet

Tags: windows, ftp, telnet

I want to check if my FTP server is active or passive. I only have the server name, user name and password. I tried to adapt this link to do it -[FTP Detect if active or passive modes are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569604/ftp-detect-if-active-or-passive-modes-are-enabled)

I can connect to this server with a GUI FTP client. But, in microsoft/windows telnet, I used the command `o ftp.myftp.com`. But, I get the error - `Could not open connection to the host on port 23:connect Failed`.

How do I fix this and find out if my server is doing active or passive ftp connections ?

Comment: Port 23 is used by a Telnet server.  Talk to your FTP server through port 21.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks. That works. Should have seen it :( But, I am happy that you left the MS forums. If possible, please ask your friends in MS to do the same. They might listen to you, but they won't listen to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active/Passive is controlled by the client, not the server.  When a client initiates a file transfer, it decides whether to perform an Active transfer (`PORT` or `EPRT` command) or a Passive transfer (`PASV` command), and as such the mode can be specified on a per-transfer basis.

FTP operates on port 21 by default, not on port 23.  You have to tell telnet which port to connect to, eg:

```
o ftp.myftp.com 21
```

When sending a `PASV` command, the response code on success is always 227, but the actual text verbage that specifies the server's listening IP/Port is unfortunately not standardized and thus differs between different FTP server vendors.  This is even mentioned in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-31):

> The format of the 227 reply to a PASV command is not well standardized.  In particular, an FTP client cannot assume that the parentheses shown on page 40 of RFC-959 will be present (and in fact, Figure 3 on page 43 omits them).  Therefore, a User-FTP program that interprets the PASV reply must scan the reply for the first digit of the host and port numbers.

[RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-31) also states:

> A server-FTP MUST implement the PASV command.

Comment: Thanks, but after putting in the correct user and pass, it says - 530 Please login with user and pass. Why ? I use the same user, pass and server in Mozilla FTP client and it works.

Comment: Telnet.exe knows nothing about FTP (or any other protocol other than Telnet, for that matter). Once you have connected to the server, you must issue all FTP commands yourself. There are multiple ways to login to an FTP server, depending on the server's capablities. If the server supports SASL, you can issue appropriate `AUTH` commands. Otherwise, use `USER`, `PASS`, and `ACCT` commands as needed. And if you connect to an FTP proxy, you may even need to use `SITE` and/or `OPEN` commands.

Comment: Look at Mozilla's own log, or use a packet sniffer like Wireshark, to see the actual FTP commands that Mozilla sends, and then replicate those commands in Telnet.exe.

Comment: I can see the mode by using a ftp client, ie Mozilla. The mode PASV can be seen in the text window pane of the tool.

Comment: That has nothing to do with logging in to a user account. Again, login is performed using `AUTH` or `USER`/`PASS`/`ACCT` commands.  Look for those in the log.